# import Findbugs/Checkstyle rules

Tags: sonarqube

I exported my Findbugs/Checkstyle rules as an xml-file from a local sonarQube instance and tried to import the xml-file into a new Quality profile on another sonarQube instance it does not work. It seems to be a formatting problem. Has anybody faced the same problem and foud a solution for it? (using 5.6.7 verison)
Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to post a valid question. Your question at this time is not complete. You need to add any errors you're getting, elaborate on the steps you have taken to produce the problem, and explain on what the desired end result is.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. You will have to choose "restore profile" on the Quality Profile page to load the exported Qauality Profile. Check the naming in the xml-file before restoring.